# newly installed 12.04 cannot connect to internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet

I am a Comp Sci student and I had to replace my dev laptop with an old Dell Inspiron 1150. First tried loading Ubuntu 13.10 but it wouldn't render graphics correctly on this old machine, so I put on 12.04 LTS instead.

During install from DVD, it recognized internet connection (I had an ethernet cable plugged into my wireless router and the linksys wireless-G adapter plugged into the bus, so I don't know which connection it was using). But now that the OS is installed, it says Network Disconnected and I can't get it to recognize either connection.

the output of

```
sudo ifconfig
```

is:

```
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask 255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:192 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:15744 (15.7 KB) TX bytes:15744 (15.7 KB)
```

and the results of

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

is:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Ethernet controller
product: BCM4401 100Base-T
vendor: Braodcom Corporation
physical id: 1
bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
version: 01
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=32
resources: memory:fcffe00-fcffffff memory:fd000000-fd003fff
```

I manually typed this in, so hoepfully no typos

Comment: "unclaimed" usually means that there is no driver installed - please search here for broadcomm or BCM.

Answer (score -1):

try requesting a new IP from the DHCP

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

releases current

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Renews IP-address of device.

Comment: "Cannot find device "eth0""